# VBA Excel export the file as .csv with keeping data in the proper columns

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I want to have the .csv file saved with the columns as they look in my mother's workbook.

I used the following code:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

```
     For Each Wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


      myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Wksht.Index).Copy
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "Address list - NEW", FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
       CreateBackup:=False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close

       Next Wksht

       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

but instead of clear data separated by columns with their title headers, I am getting everything messy in one column.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The csv file has been correctly saved. I mean comma separated. Your Excel does not open it as it should be. Try opening it as text, please. And use comma separator...

Comment: Happens to me all the time. My system list separator is a semi-colon (`;`) while the csv file gets saved with commas (`,`).

Comment: @FaneDuru: Thanks. That did that trick, but how do I do it from VBA? (Note, I'm not OP)

Comment: @VBasic2008: I posted a piece of code which I think will do the trick. But, not tested... My system uses comma as list separator and I am a little busy to change it for testing reason only. A second solution can be to use TextToColumns after opening it as it Excel default behaves.

Comment: Could you kindly test the second solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the next way of opening, please (@VBasic2008, too):

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myPath & "Address list - NEW", Origin _
        :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , Tab:=False, Comma:=True
```

If it does not work, please test the solution secommended by VBasic2008:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & "Address list - NEW", Format:=2
```

If the above solutions do not work (not tested), or even if they work but need an alternative, try the next way to split the resulted (one column) opening:

```
Private Sub testTestTextToColumns()
  Dim i As Long, sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
    Set rng = sh.Range("A:A")
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=sh.Range("A:C"), Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2))
End Sub
```

Note: The second code should process the default opening result. What you obtain now when try opening the csv...

Comment: I just figured out that it works with `Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath, Format:=2` for commas in the file, but it doesn't work for semicolons (`Format:=4`). Test it and add it to your answer (you do have semicolons as the list separator?).

Comment: @VBasic2008:  No, I have comma like list separator... That's why I did not test my code... Did you also try the `TextToColumns` processing (after the standard inconvenient opening)? I suppose it should be beyond the list separator type. Can you confirm that? I added your suggestion, but I cannot really testing it... In my case, it will anyhow open correctly.

Comment: `TextToColumn` works fine, but it's kind of ridiculous to use it when opening a file. I have tested your code and it works. I will look into `OpenText` a little deeper (never heard of it or forgotten about it) and come back to you a little later.

Comment: @VBasic2008: I tried opening files having peculiar separators ("|", for instance) using that method and it worked... That's why I supposed that it should work in your cases, too. But, not tested... The `TextToColumn` solution was provided only like alternative in case of all above it do not work. And it is not wrong to know that it may work in case of any separator, when you download/receive/simple have such a situation...

Comment: @MKR: Didn't any of the above solutions solve your problem?

Comment: It seems (it isn't) like a vast subject, so I won't get to the bottom of it that soon. Most important, I can open my comma-separated files, now. I have to figure out why my files get saved comma-separated while the system list separator is a semicolon, why the semicolon third party separated files open in one column, how to save as semicolon-separated... It'll take some time. Thanks again. [OpenText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) is pure gold. It'll take time (months) and practice to understand it all.

Comment: @VBasic2008: I would firstly try 'SaveAs' (csv) with `Local = False`. Theoretically, it will save in the standard way, not caring about the (local) list separator. But, not tested... My system localization involves the comma (standarad) separator, anyhow.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for help. The first solution was tested and worked. Really helpful :)

Comment: @MKR: Glad I could help! But should not be bad to test the others, I think. It is not bad to know what it may function when needed... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru i will do it later, as I have another project, which requires the .csv export.